# Ruby / Datamapper query comparing columns from different tables

Tags: ruby, sqlite, datamapper

I currently have a fairly simple database that is regularly updated by a script. I would like to filter the results by comparing the equality of 2 columns. The SQL query would look like:

```
SELECT devices.site_name, devices.device_name, devices.created_at
FROM devices, locations 
WHERE devices.created_at = locations.most_recent_updated_time AND devices.site_name = locations.site_name;
```

Here's my datamapper model

```
class Device
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :device_name, Text, :required => true
  property :site_name, Text, :required => true
  property :created_at, DateTime

  belongs_to :location 

end

class Location
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :site_name, Text, :required => true, :key => true
  property :most_recent_updated_time, DateTime, :required => true

  has n, :devices
end
```

Each time the script runs it appends new Device entries and updates the `:most_recent_updated_time field in the Location table. Here's an example for how the tables are updated.

```
Devices
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Device_Name ║ Site_Name ║        Created_at         ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Device1     ║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║  2 ║ Device2     ║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║  3 ║ Device3     ║ Chicago   ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
Location
╔═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ Site_Name ║ Most_Recent_Updated_Time  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║ Chicago   ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║ Boston    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

After Script Run

```
Devices
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ Device_Name ║ Site_Name ║        Created_at         ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Device1     ║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║  2 ║ Device2     ║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║  3 ║ Device3     ║ Chicago   ║ 2013-07-23T16:59:12-04:00 ║
║  4 ║ Device4     ║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-24T18:00:00-04:00 ║
║  5 ║ Device5     ║ Chicago   ║ 2013-07-24T18:00:00-04:00 ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
Location
╔═══════════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ Site_Name ║ Most_Recent_Updated_Time  ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║ Dallas    ║ 2013-07-24T18:00:00-04:00 ║
║ Chicago   ║ 2013-07-24T18:00:00-04:00 ║
║ Boston    ║ 2013-07-24T18:00:00-04:00 ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

So if I run the query after the script runs, I'd like it to return Device4 and Device5.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. Fixed, thanks! Thanks for the help also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, try adding this method to `Location`:

```
def most_recent_devices
  devices.all(:created_at => most_recent_updated_time)
end
```

Then you should be able to gather all the newest devices for each `Location` like so:

```
Location.all.map(&:most_recent_devices).flatten
```

Comment: This is going to generate alot of queries in the background ! Can't we acheive the same in a single query ?